# How do I log in to Pokemon Go on a new phone (old phone broke - didn't sign out and it is impossible) with my Google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

So my Samsung Galaxy S3 broke, the screen won't display anything, it turns on but there's no vision, I tried fixing it but it didn't work. Now I have a new phone, downloaded Pokemon Go and I can't log in due to neverending loading screen when I click Google account. I can't sign out of my account on the old phone, is that the matter? Will resetting the phone completely help or it's just the matter of server overload?

Comment: What do you mean by "there's no vision" and "I tried fixing it?"

Comment: If u logging in with the same google it should have ur account, loading screen must be depending on something else, connection failure, overload. You probably already found a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure that not signing out on your old phone wont cause any problems, its most likely that the servers are having problems. pokemon go isnt known for the best servers if you know what i mean